# Get Current Unix Epoch Time-stamp in seconds in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following C# method to get current unix epoch time stamp,

```
    public static long GetCurrentUnixTimestampSeconds()
    {
        var unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - unixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
    }
```

I need the same in SQL Server. Is it possible?

Comment: `SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', GETUTCDATE());`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just the number of seconds between epoch and current UTC time:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', sysutcdatetime());
```

Comment: How is "current UTC time" is different from "current non-UTC time" in this context?

Comment: @darw Well, it’s important to think about epoch in terms of UTC. If you replace `sysutcdatetime()` to `sysdatetime()` you’ll get the wrong answer unless you happen to be at +0:00.

Comment: In case you want it in milliseconds: `SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, '19700101', sysutcdatetime());`

Answer (score 1):

Get the current Unix timestamp (seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) in SQL.

MySQL: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`
PostgreSQL: `CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM NOW()) AS INT)`
MS SQL: `DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE())`
Oracle: `(CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE) - DATE'1970-01-01') * 86400`